Rebar через win api - что поменялось в win 7/10/11?
Все примеры с Rebar, которые я смог найти:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\winui\controls\common\rebar
MS_2020, MS_2024, git,
ещё git,
stackoverflow
Работают только если добавить:
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP

Если указать _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 или _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10 то вместо Rebar отображается узкая полоска.
Что нужно исправить / добавить чтобы примеры заработали в современных windows?
Или покажите работающий пример.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/controls/using-rebar-controls в чем ваш вопрос?

evo, в том что чтобы всё это описание заработало надо либо компилировать программу в режиме ..._WINXP, либо настраивать манифест, но информация, что дело оказывается в манифесте, закопана довольно глубоко (нашёл её только после того как пару дней протупил и затем написал здесь вопрос) и все встреченные мною примеры Rebar об этом молчали.

Нашёл, что проблему можно решить добавлением манифеста и это сработало:

Comctl32.dll версия 6 не распространяется, но она включена в Windows. Чтобы использовать Comctl32.dll версию 6, укажите ее в манифесте. Дополнительные сведения о манифестах см. в разделе Включение визуальных стилей.

Причём нашёл это предупреждение на странице про Toolbar, который хоть и не "стильно", но работает без манифеста, а там где пишут про Rebar (который без манифеста совсем не отображается) везде про это тишина.
Вот пример минимального манифеста, который делает упомянутые в вопросе примеры Rebar рабочими в современных windows без ограничения до ..._WINXP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication"
    type="win32"
/>
    
<description>Your application description here.</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

</assembly>

Он и отвечает на вопрос что изменилось в win 7/10/11 и нарушило работу примеров Rebar.
PS: Ещё нашёлся забавный набор примеров, где даже есть попытка настроить манифест, но и там работают все CommonControls... кроме Rebar, и даже тамошний вариант манифеста не помог.

Почитай ещё это https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/controls/common-control-versions

evo, это я читал ещё когда искал решение и там тоже ничего не сказано, про то что подключить ComCtl32.dll версии 6 можно только через манифест иначе Rebar версии 6 не будет работать.
С точки зрения моего вопроса всё что там написано способно только ещё больше запутать.

в том то и суть проблемы что статей много, можно долго тратить время на танцы с бубном вокруг них, но только Rebar версии 6 не будет работать без манифеста, про который все молчат.
